# Getting json data about posts

Tags: android, json

I learned in a blog reader tutorial to grap the json file and put on the code. How can I take it from a wordpress blog?

for example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=20

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i am guessing your final goal is to parse the json data after you get it from the website. Right? If that's the case, you can go about it in two ways -

1. You can directly access the URL in android application using HTTP post method giving count parameter and value 20 and get the response and decode it using JSON parser
2. If you want to do it offline i.e not connect your android device to internet, then you can simply save the data into a file and place the file in your assets folder of your application and then open the file and read it and parse it. On Chrome web-browser, you can use REST client that makes it a bit convenient to store the json data into a file.

Now, depending on which way you want to go, you will have to investigate that route to get more implementation details on the same.

HTH.

```
posts: [20]
0:  {
      id: 22313
      url: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/best-free-jquery-form-plugins-to-improve-user-experience"
      title: "Best Free jQuery Form Plugins to Improve User Experience"
      date: "2013-09-26 10:07:23"
      author: "Jake Rocheleau"
      thumbnail: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/autotab-jquery-plugin-preview-150x150.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Sure... But how can I take this URL from a wordpress site? This blog is from teamtreehouse.

Comment: Well, you first get the site contents and put it in a json string. Then user json parser to access the URL. For example, in the site you have given, the posts is the node name you are looking for. That value for that is an array of json objects (20 objects utmost). And then you access each of the json object and cue on url parameter. The value returned is what you are looking for.